# convert string as 'hours' and 'mins' into minutes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe df:

```
Time
2 hours 3 mins
5 hours 10 mins
1 hours 40 mins
10 mins
4 hours
6 hours 0 mins
```

I want to create a new column in df 'Minutes' that converts this column over to minutes

```
Minutes
123
310
100
10
240
360
```

Is there a python function to do this?
What I have tried is:

```
df['Minutes'] = pd.eval(
    df['Time'].replace(['hours?', 'mins'], ['*60+', ''], regex=True))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is ugly bug `pd.eval` processing only less like 100 rows, so after stripping `+` is called `pd.eval` in [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) for prevent it:

```
df['Minutes'] = (df['Time'].replace(['hours?', 'mins'], ['*60+', ''], regex=True)
                           .str.strip('+')
                           .apply(pd.eval))

print (df)
              Time  Minutes
0   2 hours 3 mins      123
1  5 hours 10 mins      310
2  1 hours 40 mins      100
3          10 mins       10
4          4 hours      240
5   6 hours 0 mins      360
```

---

```
#verify for 120 rows
df = pd.concat([df] * 20, ignore_index=True)


df['Minutes1'] = pd.eval(
    df['Time'].replace(['hours?', 'mins'], ['*60+', ''], regex=True).str.strip('+'))

print (df)
```

> ValueError: unknown type object

Another solution with [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and [`Series.add`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html):

```
h = df['Time'].str.extract('(\d+)\s+hours').astype(float).mul(60)
m = df['Time'].str.extract('(\d+)\s+mins').astype(float)

df['Minutes']  = h.add(m, fill_value=0).astype(int)
print (df)
              Time  Minutes
0   2 hours 3 mins      123
1  5 hours 10 mins      310
2  1 hours 40 mins      100
3          10 mins       10
4          4 hours      240
5   6 hours 0 mins      360
```

Answer (score 0):

jezrael's answer is excellent, but I spent quite some time working on this so i figured i'll post it.

You can use a `regex` to capture 'hours' and 'minutes' from your column, and then assign back to a new column after applying the logical mathematical operation to convert to minutes:

```
r = "(?:(\d+) hours ?)?(?:(\d+) mins)?"
hours = df.Time.str.extract(r)[0].astype(float).fillna(0) * 60
minutes = df.Time.str.extract(r)[1].astype(float).fillna(0)
```

---

```
df['minutes'] = hours + minutes

print(df)

              Time  minutes
0   2 hours 3 mins    123.0
1  5 hours 10 mins    310.0
2  1 hours 40 mins    100.0
3          10 mins     10.0
4          4 hours    240.0
5   6 hours 0 mins    360.0
```

I enjoy using https://regexr.com/ to test my `regex`